# Why Lubuntu runs fine from USB flash drive as LiveCD, but is extremely slow when installed on the same USB disk?

Tags: installation, lubuntu, live-usb

I have a strange problem. I have latest Lubuntu 12.04 on my USB flash drive installed as live installation (LiveCD mode). Everything runs fine and smooth, no problem with speed of the system.

But when I install Lubuntu on this same USB flash drive permanently with installer, after booting to this installed system it is extremely slow. When I run 'top' command, I see that CPU load is high at 5.2 4.8 4.2 and what is strange - there is a big percentage of CPU in Wait state, every time I try to do something in the system the Wait percentage jumps to its peak.

Can anybody help me or give me some hints what to do ? I really like Lubuntu and I would like to use it permanently from my USB flash drive, not just in "try-mode" as LiveUSB...

Thanks for any help

Comment: See another answer for moving more of the OS into ram: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72025/how-can-i-make-an-existing-persistant-live-usb-installation-load-more-of-the-os/217836#217836

Answer (score 3):

Live distro is running from RAM memory, which means booting is slow but after that, running (in RAM) is super fast. 
When you install it on USB flash it is running from flash. Flash is much slower than hard disk and hard disk is much much slower than RAM, so it is normal that in RAM Live version is faster.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think the problem might be a process that is eating too much (processor, memory, disk).

To check, use `htop` (for memory and processor) and `iotop` (for disk)

To install, `sudo apt-get install htop iotop`. Htop runs fine as user, but to run iotop, you need to do `sudo iotop`

---

My suspection, though, is that the problem is that you are using the thumb drive for /tmp (the temporary files folder) and for swap (another kind of "temporary memory"). That eould probably be avoided if you, instead, installed the thumb drive with a "persistent mode" instalation.