# lubuntu 12.10 usb drive stop connections after software update, screen resolution also not working well

Tags: 12.10, wireless, lubuntu, screen, live-usb

Few days ago I had a little problem with my hard disks, and after that, I'm running my computer with a lubuntu live usb. First I made a live usb with no persistence, and it runs fine on every machine I have tested. But changing options like keyboard style, wireless passwords and so on every boot is no good. So I re-write a live usb with persistence, and it runs ok. It boots slower than the stick with no persistence, but every thing seems to be ok. I decided to make a software update, and it gaves me an error (witch I not remember exactly) on the end of process. In the same boot I try to remove the english translation pack, due I'm speak portuguese. Everything seems to be ok, I rebooted the machine, and the lubuntu screen (after choose to try without changes on computer) go to an weird text mode, the boot take more time to complete, and when the system is ready, the screen resolution is wrong, with less definition and feels like streched, and so my wi-fi connection doesn't work. I'm able to choose `enable network`, but nothing happens. I believe that if I re-write my usb stick the problem can be solved, but I'm looking for a `less invasive` intervention. Oh, I forget to mention that I tried to change the screen resolution when booted, but no options fits my screen.
Sorry for my bad english, thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks for help. Just another quest: do you think its safe to complete install by using this same usb with problems? I dont know if the installation files have been changed in this software updates. Just being curious. I think its more prudent to do it again by begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A persistent Live USB is not a full install.** Software updates may fail because there may not be enough space in the USB. Doing extensive modification to the OS in a persistent USB may give you unintended results. I recommend a full install in USB as described in [How do I Install Lubuntu 12.04 on a USB drive (the full installation)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266440/how-do-i-install-lubuntu-12-04-on-a-usb-drive-the-full-installation)

To do a full install on a USB, you will need a media to install from. This can be a (persistent) Live USB or a Live DVD.

**A few things to remember:**

1. If you use a Live USB to install from, **you will need a second USB
   to install to.** In other words, you cannot use just one USB.
2. The USB for full install needs to be at least 8GB, preferably more. A
   full install takes more space than a persistent live USB. Then
   updates and personal data will take even more space.
3. If you use 2 USBs and the computer has a working hard disk(s). It is
   very important not to get confused between these things while
   installation. **A full installation in the target USB will erase
   everything in that USB.** If you target a hard drive instead of the
   right USB, you will lose all the data in that hard drive!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm, understand! Thanks for help and the very good, complete and quickly answers.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer is correct, consider accepting it by putting a green tick mark next to it. This will help others with similar problems.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was searching for this while you type!
(: